# Is there some pattern behind the many VIM commands?

Tags: vim, editor

I have to add a VIM personality to an IDE. I never used VIM for more than the most basic edits and i'm now overwhelmed by the complexity of the command structure.

Is there any overall structure for the combination of counts moves and insert/delete commands?
I just can't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, there is obviously a finger position pattern behind <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>.

The fact that <kbd>^</kbd> goes to the beginning of a line and <kbd>$</kbd> goes to the end is patterned on common regular expression syntax.

<kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> page forward and back, and that's fairly intuitive.

<kbd>i</kbd> inserts (before) and <kbd>a</kbd> appends (after the cursor). Similarly,
<kbd>I</kbd> inserts at the beginning of the line, and <kbd>A</kbd> appends at the very end.

<kbd>></kbd> and <kbd><</kbd> indent and outdent, respectively. That's also kind of intuitive.

But on the whole, many of the other commands are on whatever keys were left – it's hard to find an intuitive mapping between the letters of the alphabet and an editor's commands.

Repeat counts are always entered before a command, and mostly repeat the command that many times, but in some cases do something clever but analogous.

I think the secret to not going crazy over `vi` is to start out with only a small handful of commands. I have a lot of colleagues who don't know to do anything other than

- move the cursor around using the arrow keys (you don't have to use <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>);
- insert with <kbd>i</kbd>, delete with <kbd>Del</kbd> (you don't have to use <kbd>x</kbd>);
- delete a line with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
- get out of input mode with <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- get out of vi with <kbd>:x</kbd> (exit) or <kbd>q!</kbd> (quit, and throw away my changes!)

Because I'm much smarter, the additional commands I know and use are:

- go to the top of the file with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>, the bottom with <kbd>G</kbd>.
  I can go to a specified line number with (line-number)<kbd>G</kbd>.
- copy a line with <kbd>y</kbd> (yank), paste it with <kbd>p</kbd>
- change a word with <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, the rest of the line with <kbd>C</kbd>
- delete a word with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, the rest of the line with <kbd>D</kbd>
- I sometimes use <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat the last command, or <kbd>u</kbd> (undo) if I messed up.

When you have occasion to use other commands, you can teach them to yourself one by one as needed.

Answer (score 10):

[This is a good article](http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html) for explaining the VIM philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

I think the characteristic that better defines VIM in respect to other editors is its wide array of motion commands. The first thing to learn to fully use VIM is hitting the arrow keys as little as possible, and think at the text in terms of "blocks" like "a sentence" "a tag" "a word" "a group of brackets".

Say you have `function foo($bar, $fooz)` you can change the parameters by simply positioning your cursor anywhere inside the brackets and pressing `ci)` (mnemonic: change inner bracket). The same pattern applies to other commands: yank (`y`), delete (`d`) and so on.

I know this doesn't explain the whole "VIM philosophy" but combining normal mode commands with the vast amount of motion modifiers is what really made me see the light.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of nice and interesting tutorials. One example is

http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/vim_tutorial.html

But the broad structure that most of them would give you is

1. There are two main modes for editing - Command mode and insert mode. You can move from insert mode to command mode using the  key.
2. You can execute commands in the command mode by typing a single key or a sequence of keys.
3. Commands can help you achieve a wide variety of things 
   deletion of lines - dd
   yanking (copying of lines ) - yy
   pasting lines below the current line - p
   pasting lines above the current line - P ( and so on)

   Most commands in the command mode can be pre-fixed by a "count" to indicate the number of times the command has to be executed. For example, 3dd would delete three lines.

   One set of commands in the command mode lets you move to the insert mode. That is explained below.
4. There are different ways of entering the insert mode from the command mode. Prominent among them are (i-insert at cursor, I-insert at beginning of line, o-insert a line below, O-insert a line above, a-append, A-append at end of line.

The quick reference at

http://www.andy-roberts.net/misc/vim/vim.pdf

Will help you understand the relevance of "count"